# Bitmapfactory example

Tags: android

I want to create a dynamic image view where every image in my gallery will going to use bitmapfactory and not image drawable that binds in the image view. Is there some sites that has bitmapfactory tutorial for this? i believe that using bitmapfactory uses less memory that binding the image into image view? Is this right? I want also to minimize the risk of memory leaks thats why I want to use bitmapfactory. Please help. I cant find basic examples that teaches bitmapfactory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Building Bitmap Objects**

1) *From a File*

Use the adb tool with push option to copy test2.png onto the sdcard

This is the easiest way to load bitmaps from the sdcard. Simply pass the path to the image to BitmapFactory.decodeFile() and let the Android SDK do the rest.

```
public class TestImages extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/test2.png");
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
    }
}
```

All this code does is load the image test2.png that we previously copied to the sdcard. The BitmapFactory creates a bitmap object with this image and we use the `ImageView.setImageBitmap()` method to update the ImageView component.

2) *From an Input stream*

Use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()` to convert a BufferedInputStream into a bitmap object.

```
public class TestImages extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
        FileInputStream in;
        BufferedInputStream buf;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/test2.png");
            buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
            image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
            if (in != null) {
            in.close();
            }
            if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This code uses the basic Java FileInputStream and BufferedInputStream to create the input stream for `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. The file access code should be surrounded by a try/catch block to catch any exceptions thrown by FileInputStream or BufferedInputStream. Also when you're finished with the stream handles they should be closed.

3) *From your Android project's resources*

Use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id)` to get a bitmap from an Android resource.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
```

Comment: thanks.. by the way did you know how to use bitmap recycle? i think it reduces memory usage if im right..

Comment: @nelzkie yes recycling bitmap will tell the garbage collector that he can free object associated to that bitmap

Comment: @nelzkieif you want to load large bitmap, recycle will have no effect, but insteed you will have to use inSampleSize to load with an efficient way your bitmap.

Comment: @nelzkie refer to this StackOverflow thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966
and this one for insamplesize http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @nelzkie for recycle() just use bitmapObj.recycle() when you are sure there are no further uses for this bitmapObj, plz  accept the answer if this is what you are looking for