# Android: I have an actionbar and listview within the actionbar. How do I display an image in new view when I click on an item in the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, imageview

I am new to Android and I have this issue:

I have created a tab action bar and have list items within the action bar. Now when I click on one of the list item, I want an image to be displayed in new screen. How do I do this?

Comment: Please show some of the code that you have so far. Unfortunately the "how do I do this, I have no idea" questions are not suitable for this site. You need to display some understanding of what you're trying to do, even if it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create an new `Activity` with the image in it when the `ListView` was clicked. Create a listener  to handle the clicks from the `ListView` and start the Activity from that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that and I get a nullpointer exception. The image is not decoding
here is the code for displaying the image in image view
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_file);
  String imageFileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("IMG_FILE_NAME");
  Log.d("Filename in the Imageview" + TAG,TEST_IMGLOADER_PATH + imageFileName);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
    .decodeFile(TEST_IMGLOADER_PATH + imageFileName));

Comment: Can you post what you did? I can't show you what's wrong if you just explain the error in one sentence.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bitmaps being used for ImageViews. If you want, ask another question about that, I believe I answered yours. See this tutorial if you want to use their code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182714/bitmapfactory-example