# Problems loading a large bitmap into an Android app

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've followed [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) and ctrl-v'd the recommended methods into my code. Setting the imageview looks like this:

```
        iv.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.myPic, 200, 200));
```

And yet the image doesn't display. The screen goes black, LogCat indicates that memory has been allocated, but nothing appears.

Comment: Where have you placed the `ImageView`? Have you tried copying the code directly, without modifications, and seeing whether that works?

Comment: It's right in the middle of a RelativeLayout. It's just a RelativeLayout with an ImageView centered in the middle of it. And all I did was ctrl-v the code but with private instead of public static.

Comment: Could you try testing the third method proposed in the solution to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182714/bitmapfactory-example

Just to confirm you can at least display the image. Then we could focus on whether `decodeSampledBitmapFactory` is doing what's expected. How large is your image?

Comment: Generally, if you have a method which can operate independently of a class, you should keep it static. It may be useful for other areas of your application later on to utilise the functionality you're developing here.

Comment: I made a mistake, I used Thread.sleep() rather than SystemClock.sleep(). Sorry about this.