# BitmapFactory returning null Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to get the Bitmap from a URL from the `StaticConfig.getMyUser().getAvatar()`. The url is as follows `"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0feEeEohl8I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/htLteFBdk5M/s96-c/photo.jpg"`.

When I use the code below, `src` is null. I'm not sure why. I am currently looking into [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182714/bitmapfactory-example) but I'm still clueless to what I should do.

```
private void setImageAvatar(Context context){
    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap src;
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(StaticConfig.getMyUser().getAvatar(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    src = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
    if(src == null){
        Log.e("UserProf","src is null");
    }
    // code to do something with src here
}
```

Comment: You need to download image from server first

Comment: You probably need a image loader try [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: and how would I place this into a `byte[]`? Because as I can see, I would have to place it in the ImageView right away and then get the bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by others, the ideal way would be to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Because it handles many things, from caching to memory optimisation for you.
for eg. with Glide you will just have to write

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0feEeEohl8I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/htLteFBdk5M/s96-c/photo.jpg")
     .into(imgview);
```

Or If you want to write manually, you can use below method.
**imageview** is instance of initialized Imageview.

```
public void setBitmapFromNetwork(){

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            bitmap = getBitmapFromLink();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageview.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }});
    }};
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}


public Bitmap getBitmapFromLink() throws IOException{
    HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0feEeEohl8I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/htLteFBdk5M/s96-c/photo.jpg").openConnection());
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    InputStream ism = conn.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ism);
    if (ism != null) {
        ism .close();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

And please make sure you have given Internet permission in manifest.

Comment: did you mean `openConnection()`? If so, it's giving me an error. `Incompatible types. Required: java.net.HttpURLConnection Found: java.net.URLConnection`

Comment: Pardon me. Actually i had tired in kotlin . forgot to typecast in java. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Apparently, this code is printing out a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I created a new thread but it only generated more errors

Comment: I didn't find any issue with previous method in thread. Check the updated answer with complete code you need.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to download image from that url.
It's better to use a image loader like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: How should I place it in `byte[]` then?

Comment: You can get a bitmap from glide as :

Bitmap theBitmap = Glide.
        with(this).
        load("http://....").
        asBitmap().
        into(100, 100). 
        get();

Then decode this bitmap as byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to use kotlin version.

```
class SetBitmapFromNetwork(img: ImageView?): AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

    var img:ImageView? = img

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?): Bitmap {

        val conn: HttpURLConnection = (URL("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-0feEeEohl8I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGA/htLteFBdk5M/s96-c/photo.jpg").openConnection()) as HttpURLConnection

        conn.doInput = true

        val ism: InputStream = conn.inputStream

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ism)


    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Bitmap?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        img?.setImageBitmap(result)
    }
}
```

Just call as,

```
SetBitmapFromNetwork(img).execute()
```