# Array of images stored in a memory mobile

Tags: android, arrays

I use this xml for to create an array of images in drawable folder:

```
<array name="icons">
        <item>@drawable/i1</item>
        <item>@drawable/i2</item>
.....
```

I need to do the same with images stored in the memory of the mobile.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These drawables are bundled with your APK. They are static.

In order to retrieve icons from the phone's memory you have to go another way.

For example load it as a bitmap: [Bitmapfactory example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182714/bitmapfactory-example)